# How can change scale in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

For example, I wanna get a figure like this

1) x coordinate is from 4, 5, 6 then to 20, but y coordinate is $10^{-4}$, $10^{-3}$, $10^{-2}$, $10^{-1}$, and 1.

2) what is commands of log-log plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
set log y
```

2)

```
set log x
set log y
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Bernhard's answer, you could also try:

1) `set logscale y`

2) `set logscale xy`

If you want base other than 10, like say 2, then use `set logscale y 2`